# Websockets with Snap won't bind in production

Tags: haskell, websocket

please help me with something:
I want to implement websockets-snap in production but they seem that won't take the address. I have the following code:

`the js inside index.html file`

```
function createChatSocket() {
    if(window.location.host == '') {
        /* Running on localhost */
        return new WebSocket('ws://35.197.208.147/ws/console/');
    } else {
        /* Running in "production" */
        return new WebSocket('wss://jaspervdj.be/websockets/example/chat/');
    }
}
```

the window.location.host is not empty, it is the ip

`the server.hs file`

```
app :: Snap ()
app = Snap.route
    [ ("",               Snap.ifTop $ Snap.serveFile "./shorts/index.html")
    , ("console", console)
    ]
....
....
....
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
console :: Snap ()
console = do
    state <- liftIO $ newMVar newServerState
    WS.runWebSocketsSnap $ application state
```

No matter what i do, it will always return the websockets found on `wss://jaspervdj.be/websockets/example/chat/` and not my server. What can i do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's a JavaScript issue, not a Haskell one. The [`window.location.host`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLHyperlinkElementUtils/host) will **never** be empty. Therefore, you always end up with the websocket to jaspervdj.be.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, my fault, it was late night. Yet if i erase the else and leave only the ip won't work. I will try another solutions and get back. Thanks